# Print checked values in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to print checked values of checkbox list from a JSP page but nothing appears even if some selections are there.

```jsp
<form action="process" method="POST">
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list.items}">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkSkills" value="${$item.Id}">${item.name}
</c:forEach>        
<input type="submit" name="Getvalue" value="Get value" />
</form>
```

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
String[] Answers = request.getParameterValues("chkSkills");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

String ButClicked = request.getParameter("Getvalue");
if (ButClicked != null) {
        for (String Answer : Answers) {
            out.print(Answer + "<br>");
        }
    }
    //processRequest(request, response);
}
```

Comment: It's a typo, however you shouldn't get values in this way. Doing like this is already a bug. Also it's unclear what are you asking?

Comment: I am trying to print all checked values of the checkbox list.

Comment: I am display the values in the checkbox list

Comment: Where do you print them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your `value` attribute to

```
value="${item.Id}"
```

Notice, there's no need to put a `$` inside the `{}` again.